# C# - Get a list of subscribers listening to a RoutedEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, routed-events, subscriber

I'm trying to get a list of objects that are subscribing to the PasswordBox PasswordChanged event.

The PasswordBox has a static readonly RoutedEvent `PasswordChangedEvent` and an instance `PasswordChanged` event.

Thanks!

Comment: To what end? Surely the point of events (in most event-based models) is that you don't care how many listeners there are, what they're doing with the information, etc.

Comment: Unit Testing... I want to ensure that that my object is listening to the event. :)

Comment: Think of it another way. Register for the PasswordChanged event, modify the PasswordBox value, verify your listener was called. Much simpler then trying to get the list of subscribers external to the control.

Comment: @Aaron, that's actually a good suggestion and works in this situation. Thanks. You should place it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can look at this a different way.

Register for the `PasswordChanged` event, modify the `PasswordBox` value, then verify your listener was called with the provided value.

Since you have a reference to the control this will be much easier then attempting to acquire the list of subscribers external to the control.